# How to convert numbers like 902.1 or 902 to 900 in php

Tags: php

Anyone knows how i can convert How to convert numbers like 902.1 or 902 to 900 in php..i have tried both ceil and floor like below but still same issue

```
$amount = 902.1
  $amount2 = floor($amount);
  return $amount2;

   returns 902
```

but i want to return either 900 or 910..something like this

Comment: i just want to round it to nearest 10th...becos the api i am using dont allow values like 902, or 903 or this kind of numbers...its only 910, 920 , 110 and this kind format

Comment: @trey..yes it does

Comment: _“i have tried both ceil and floor”_ - those round up or down to the next _integer_ value. Since you are starting out with integer values already, _of course_ both do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me

```
$number = ceil($amount / 10) * 10;
```